# In sql, is the length function O(1) or O(length)

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

In sql, is calling length(VARCHAR column) O(1) or O(length)?

Related: Are VARCHAR strings stored as length-prefixed strings (aka pascal strings), or as null terminated strings?

The implementations I care about are sqlite and postgresql, but feel free to answer for others.

Comment: This would be an implementation detail that *could* change by version, or product.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Postgres [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html):

> The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte
>   plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case
>   of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1.

This strongly suggests that Postgres, as with many other databases, uses length encoding for the value.  That is the first byte or four bytes stores the length of the string.  The data is stored after that on the database page.

With this storage structure, any reasonable implementation of the length function would be O(1).

Comment: See also [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html), which may store particularly long strings compressed and/or out of the main "page", reusing this length marker to indicate the technique(s) used on that string.

Comment: @IMSoP . . . Thank you for the reference.  Interestingly enough, even in the case of TOAST, the length is the total datum size, so length is still O(1).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle at least, they are not stored as null-terminated.  The database responds with the length of the string as stored in the database.

This would make it O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Both Postgres and SQLite internally store strings with a length prefix, but that value is designed for storage and measures the length in *bytes*.

The `length` function returns the number of *characters*, which can be different from the byte length in any multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8. So in practice, it's very likely that `length` has to scan the string.

(This will probably not matter in practice; if you have enough data, the most likely bottleneck is disk I/O.)